# Service calling another service

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a *Service A* using another *Service B* (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) as following:

```
export class ServiceA {       
   private testMap: Map<string, string> = new Map();

   constructor(private serviceB: ServiceB) {}

   getTestMap(): Observable<Map<string, string>> {
      this.serviceB.getSomething(new HttpParams()).(data => {
         this.testMap.set('A', data);
      }
   }
}
```

and a component calls the map defined above as:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.getTestMap();
}

getTestMap(): void {
   this.serviceA.getTestMap().subscribe(data => this.componentMap = data);

}
```

The data I got in the component is undefined. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the component, `getTestMap(): void { this.serviceB.getTestMap()` ... is that a typo in this question? In other words, should/is the component calling `this.serviceA.getTestMap()`?

Comment: yes, it's a typo. I've corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`getTestMap()` from ServiceA should return an `Observable`. In your example you don't return anything. It could look like that (provided `this.serviceB.getSomething()` also returns an `Observable`):

```js
export class ServiceA {       
   private testMap: Map<string, string> = new Map();

   constructor(private serviceB: ServiceB) {}

   getTestMap(): Observable<Map<string, string>> {
      return this.serviceB.getSomething(new HttpParams())
        .pipe(
          tap(data => this.testMap.set('A', data)),
          map(() => this.testMap)
        );
   }
}
```

And in your component:

```js
ngOnInit(){
   this.getTestMap();
}

getTestMap(): void {
   this.serviceA.getTestMap().subscribe(data => this.componentMap = data);
}
```

Some useful resources:

- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable
- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators

Comment: Thanks, @madder. yes, ServiceB also returns an Observable. 

 I tested as:
ngOnInit(){
   this.getTestMap();
   console.log(this.componentMap);
}

I have checked the resources but I still cannot make it work. Neither does the solution provided. 

Thank you.

Comment: It works! Thanks!! (i am not familiar with the lifecycle hooks and printed in the wrong palce)

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the getTestMap method  should be like:

```
getTestMap(): Observable<Map<string, string>> {
      return this.serviceB.getSomething(new HttpParams()).(data => {
         this.testMap.set('A', data);
    return data;
      }
   }
```

Comment: missed return observable from the method. Updated it. it will work now.